# Flask serving Tensorflow

Tags: python, flask, tensorflow, apache2, mod-wsgi

I create a flask app to serve tensorflow model. The app works good on localhost but when I want to serve it with apache with mod_wsgi I get an error:
ImportError: No module Tensorflow found
Tensorflow is installed and I used it in simple python script and I tested the flask app locally without any problem
How can I import tensorflow in flask app served by apache2

Comment: What version of Python is mod_wsgi compiled for? It has to be same version as you want to use. Are you using a Python virtual environment and have you told mod_wsgi to use it? For virtual environment read http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html but realise you can't force mod_wsgi to use a virtual environment from a different version of Python than it was compiled for.

Comment: I have only python 2.7 instaled in ubuntu server, I will check mod_wsgi python version tonight. I tried without virtual environment and it didn't worked. I read that LD_LIBRARY_PATH is cleared inside flask. may be this the problem with no loading tensorflow

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH is only relevant if dealing with C extension modules that haven't been linked properly to libraries. It is unlikely to be that.

Comment: Are you using mod_wsgi daemon mode? How have you configured mod_wsgi?

Comment: I am new to flask, I usually use Ruby on Rails, I just installed mod_wsgi and set the host file in apache with wsgi alias,  I am not using mod_wsgi daemon, how can I configure mod_wsgi?

Comment: Have you looked at all at the Flask documentation at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/mod_wsgi/ or the mod_wsgi documentation at http://www.modwsgi.org

Comment: I created a virtualenv for the app and I installed all the needed packages in  it and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a virtual env for the flask app and install al the packages in the env and the app workd well